# Анимация при наведении на ссылку

Tags: javascript, css

Как сделать чтобы при наведении на ссылку цвет менялся слева направо в течении 2 секунд например с синего на красный. Перелопатил кучу сайтов но ничего путного не нашёл.Спасибо.
P.S. Желательно чтобы посещённыё ссылки отмечалось фиолетовым цветом.

Answer (score 3):

Вы что-то такое искали?

```css
a{
  font-size: 72px;
  color: black
}
a:visited {
  color: violet;
}

.text-animation:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red,blue); 
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;  
  animation: text-animation 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes text-animation {
    to {
        background-position: 170vh;
    }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class = 'text-animation'>Texxxxttttt</a>
```

Comment: Нехватает подробностей, что за что отвечает. Напишите в вопросе, просто по тексту "Вы что-то такое искали?", не особо понятно что именно происходит. Ну или хотя бы оставьте ссылки на пропорции которые вы использовали, кроме самых примитивных по типу `color`, `background-image` и т.п.